# Find only the first few matched files using find

Tags: find

Say there are hundreds of `*.txt` files in a directory. I only want to find the first three `*.txt` files and then exit the searching process.

How can I achieve this using the `find` utility? I had a quick look through its man pages but saw no option for this.

Comment: You can use `find . -name  '*.txt' -print -quit` only show the first match and let `find` exit after the first match. I do not know if it is possible to adapt to the case "exit after finding n matches".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could pipe the output of `find` through `head`:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | head -n 3
```

Comment: I knew this, I want exit the searching process after finding out the first three matched files. There can be huge amount of matched files I don't care.

Comment: I think the find command does get terminated once head has printed the first 3 files

Comment: Yes, it's strange, but you are right.

Comment: It's not at all strange - it's how pipes work in UNIX. `head` starts up and waits for input from the lefthand side of the pipe. Then `find` starts up and searches for files that match the criteria specified, sending its output through the pipe. When `head` has received and printed the number of lines requested, it terminates, closing the pipe. `find` notices the closed pipe and it also terminates. Simple, elegant and efficient.

Comment: Isn't that `head -n3`, though? I always use it that way, and the man page for GNU coreutils-8.5 head(1) doesn't seem to indicate that just using `-3` is a supported syntax.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: From the coreutils man page: "For compatibility head also supports an obsolete option syntax -countoptions, which is recognized only if it is specified first. count is a decimal number optionally followed by a size letter (‘b’, ‘k’, ‘m’) as in -c, or ‘l’ to mean count by lines, or other option letters (‘cqv’)." GNU calling this "obsolete" seems overly optimistic to me; as far as I know, this style is _far_ more common.

Comment: @Plutor I don't see that in the Debian Squeeze coreutils-8.5 man page for `head`. Though if it works, then that's well enough. I do think it could be added to the answer, though, particularly since the man page *does* state `with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file` (for `-n`).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That was quoted from the coreutils 8.21 manual on gnu.org. Not sure about Debian's manual. http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#head-invocation

Comment: To summarize, `-n 3` is [POSIX compatible](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/head/), and therefore likely to be more portable.

Comment: +1 to @D_Bye I feel I just learned a ton of Unix after reading `It's not at all strange - it's how pipes...`'s comment.

Comment: @D_Bye Your explanation isn't perfectly accurate. See my answer here.

Answer (score 18):

[This other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68417/108618) is somewhat flawed. The command is

> ```
> find . -name '*.txt' | head -n 3
> ```

Then there's an explanation [in one of the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68414/only-find-first-few-matched-files-using-find#comment98986_68417) [emphasis mine]:

> `head` starts up and waits for input from the lefthand side of the pipe. Then `find` starts up and searches for files that match the criteria specified, sending its output through the pipe. When `head` has received and printed the number of lines requested, it terminates, closing the pipe. **`find` notices the closed pipe and it also terminates.** Simple, elegant and **efficient**.

This is *almost* true.

**The problem is `find` notices the closed pipe only when it tries to write to it – in this case it's when the 4th match is found. But if there's no 4th match then `find` will continue. Your shell will wait!** If it happens in a script, the script will wait, despite the fact we already know the pipe output is final and nothing can be added to it. Not so efficient.

The effect is negligible if this particular `find` finishes fast by itself but with complex search in a large file tree the command may unnecessarily delay whatever you want to do next.

The not-so-perfect solution is to run

```
( find … & ) | head -n 3
```

This way when `head` exits, the shell continues immediately. Background `find` process may be ignored then (it will exit sooner or later) or targeted with `pkill` or something.

---

To prove the concept you may search for `/`. We expect one match only, yet `find` looks for it everywhere and it may take a lot of time.

```
find / -name / 2>/dev/null | head -n 1
```

Terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as soon as you see the issue. Now compare:

```
pidof find ; ( find / -name / 2>/dev/null & ) | head -n 1 ; pidof find
```

---

A better solution may be:

```bash
yes | head -n 2 \
| find … -print -exec sh -c '
   read dummy || kill -s PIPE "$PPID"
' find-sh \;
```

Notes:

- Here we want 3 matched files, but we use `head -n 2` (not `head -n 3`). After the third matching file, `read` finds no input on its stdin and then `kill` terminates `find`. If we used `head -n 3`, then `kill` would be triggered after the fourth file.
- The signal is `SIGPIPE`. `kill -s INT …` should work as well. I deliberately chose `SIGPIPE` because it's the signal that terminates `find` in the simplest solution (`find … | head -n 3`).
- Running one `sh` per matching file will be negligible if you want 3 files. Remember our goal is to avoid this `find` (from what I called "not-so-perfect solution") running in the background in vain; for the overall performance of the OS, few short-living shells instead of "abandoned" `find` that traverses the filesystem are better for sure. But if you want (at most) 1000 files and the chances are `find` may run out of files even earlier (so there may be no problem we want to avoid), then these shells are a burden.

  The following code spawns reduced number of `sh` processes, but I think it's flawed:

  ```bash
  # flawed, DO NOT USE
  yes | head -n 999 \
  | find … -exec sh -c '
     for pathname do
        printf "%s\\n" "$pathname"
        read dummy || { kill -s PIPE "$PPID"; exit 0; }
     done
  ' find-sh {} +
  ```

  I had to replace `-print` (from the outside of the shell code) with `printf …` (inside the shell code). The reason is `-print` before `-exec sh … {} +` could (and probably would) print too many pathnames.

  A potential problem arises: if each `printf` created a separate process, then it would make this "optimization" pointless. Fortunately in almost(?) every `sh` `printf` is a builtin.

  But the real flaw is the fact `exec sh … {} +` waits for as many pathnames as possible before handing them over to `sh`. On one hand this is exactly what reduces the number of `sh` processes. On the other hand it's almost certain that when the 1000th match is enqueued, `find` will keep searching for 1001st; and when the 1001st is found, probably for even more. Note in this case the 1001st match is the one that would terminate `find … | head -n 1000`; so the flawed solution is even worse than the simplest solution, do not use it.
- The simplest solution (`find … | head -n 3`) will miscount if there's a newline character in one of the printed pathnames. If you want null-terminated strings then the simplest solution will become like `find … -print0 | head -z -n 3`, i.e. you will need `head` that supports this non-portable option `-z`. In our optimized solution you will need neither `head -z` nor `find -print0`; `printf "%s\\0" "$pathname"` in the shell code will be enough.
- Counting is done inside `sh` by consuming lines from the stdin inherited from `find`. Usually you don't pipe anything to `find`, but in general you may want to do this for some purpose other than our counting. The other purpose and our counting method will be incompatible then.
- `yes` is not portable. For our purpose `while :; do echo; done` is a portable replacement.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

---

A fellow user asked for a shell function that implements the solution. Here it is:

```
findn () (
  n="$1"
  shift
  case "$n" in
    '' | *[!0123456789]*) echo >&2 not a valid number; 
  exit 1;;
  esac
  [ "$n" -eq 0 ] && exit 0
  n="$((n-1))"
  while :; do echo; done | head -n "$n" \
  | find "$@" -exec sh -c '
     read dummy || kill -s PIPE "$PPID"
  ' find-sh \;
)
```

The first argument is the maximum number of matches you want, the rest will be given to `find`. Notes:

- The `case` is because of this: [*Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103/108618).
- While running `find`, the function appends `-exec …`, so there will never be an implicit `-print`. If you want results to be printed, specify `-print` explicitly.

Example usage:

```
findn 2 / -name bin -print 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Could you make your final snippet into a general-purpose script, or bash function at least? i.e. replace `...` and `999` etc. with variables to be provided via the cmdline?

Comment: @einpoklum Now I think the final snippet (the one with `-exec … {} +`) is badly flawed. I will improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `find` that might work for many is to use `fd` instead, a find-like tool written in Rust. ([fd is a simple, fast and user-friendly alternative to find](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd))

```bsh
fd --glob '*.txt' /path/to/search --max-results $n
```

Comment: Note that the command is called `fdfind` (from `fd-find` package, since 2018) on Debian-based systems, `fd` being a file manager in the `fdclone` package (since 1997).

Comment: You'd need to add `-uu` to get a closer equivalent to the find command.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` 4.4+ and GNU tools, to exit as early as possible as soon as the 3rd file has been found, you can do:

```
n=3
readarray -td '' first_3_files < <(
  (
    echo "$BASHPID"
    LC_ALL=C exec stdbuf -o0 find . -name '*.txt' -type f -print0
  ) | {
    IFS= read -r pid
    head -zn "$n"
    kill -s PIPE "$pid"
  }
)

echo "The first $n files are:"
printf ' - %s\n' "${first_3_files[@]}"
```

`stdbuf -o0` stops `find` buffering its output, and we send the SIGPIPE signal to `find` as soon as `head -zn 3` returns, rather than letting `find` carry on searching and only receive the SIGPIPE when it finds and prints the 4th file path.

Or another GNU specific approach using GNU `find`'s `-quit` predicate:

```
n=3
readarray -td '' first_3_files < <(
  seq "$((n - 1))" | LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 \
   ! -exec read iteration ';' -quit)
```

(if your system doesn't have a standalone `read` utility, use `-exec sh -c 'read iteration' ';'`; systems with a standalone `read` utility probably has it implemented as a shell script wrapper around the builtin `read` anyway).

With `zsh`, you can just do:

```
first_3_files=( **/*.txt(ND.Y3) )
```