# Bash script - check if any files changed recently

Tags: bash, find, stat

I am writing a script which needs to check if any of the files in a given directory have been modified recently. I thought I could simply use `find`, however it reports success even if it doesn't find a match:

```
$ touch afile
$ find . -mtime -1 -iname ????*
./afile
$ echo $?
0
$ find . -mtime +1 -iname ????*
$ echo $?
0
```

(I'm just using the iname predicate to exclude '.' here - but same behaviour with `-type f`)

I would prefer not to have to parse the output of `ls` as this [can be temperamental](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2045).

Using `test -n "$(find . -mtime -1 -iname ????*)"` seems to give the desired result but doesn't strike me as a particularly elegant solution.

I don't need to know which files have been modified - only if ANY have changed recently (where "recently" will usually be 1 day).

Is there a better way to do this?

(searching Google, I just get lots of SEO crap on how to execute a simple find)

Comment: What operating system are you using or, more specifically, what `find` implementation? Should we assume GNU tools?

Comment: What certainly might speed up the process is adding `-print -quit` at the end, i.e. quitting after the first match (and priting the file for testing output vs. no output).

Comment: You have to quote the glob patterns passed to `find`, otherwise the shell may interpret them!   `find . -name '*.jpg'` not `-name *.jpg`.

Comment: Related: [How to stop the find command after first match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62880)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you have seen, you cannot use find's exit code for something like this. The exit code is only about whether or not the command ran successfully, it has nothing to do with whether or not files were found. After all, finding no files isn't a failure, it is a success: you got the correct result, no files. This is explained in `man find` (the quote is from GNU find):

> EXIT STATUS
>
> find  exits  with  status  0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur.
> This is deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value is non-zero,  you  should  not
> rely on the correctness of the results of **find**.
>
> When some error occurs, find may stop immediately, without completing all the actions specified.  For
> example,  some  starting  points  may  not have been examined or some pending program invocations for
> **-exec ... {} +** or **-execdir ... {} +** may not have been performed.

You could indeed use `-n $(find ...)`, I don't really see an issue there. Since file names cannot contain `NUL`, I cannot think of a case that would break that. If you want something slightly cleaner, you could try using an array and then testing whether the number of elements in the array is more than `0`. Something like this:

```
$ findResults=( $(find . -mtime -1 -iname '????*' | head -n1) )
$ [[ ${#findResults[@]} -gt 0 ]] && echo "Found files!" || echo "No files found!"
Found files!

$ findResults=( $(find . -mtime +1 -iname '????*' | head -n1) )
$ [[ ${#findResults[@]} -gt 0 ]] && echo "Found files!" || echo "No files found!"
No files found!
```

Frankly, however, I am not sure this is any better than the simpler `[[ -n $(find ...) ]] && echo found || echo nope`.

Comment: Since `-quit` is not POSIX, a `find ... | head -n 1` might speed up the process for larger sets of files.

Comment: Ah yes, good point, @FelixJN, thanks.

Comment: @FelixJN Piping to `head` is [somewhat "flawed"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373065/108618) though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski uff ... `-print -print`  in `find` would be POSIX as far as I can see. A bit cumbersome.

Comment: @FelixJN A bit cumbersome, but IMO brilliant, at least in case of `head -n 1`. Thanks!

Comment: @FelixJN, no that would likely not help as `find` will buffer its output, so will print those 2 lines at once. Even if it didn't it's unlikely that `head` would have been scheduled and exited in between the 2 writes.

Comment: Invoking split+glob on the output of `find` in `findResults=( $(find . -mtime -1 -iname '????*' | head -n1) )` makes little sense definitely a lot less than doing `[ -n "$(find... |head -n1)" ]`.

Comment: Using `A && B || C` in place of `if A; then B; else C; fi` is really bad practice, I wish people didn't advertise its usage here.

Comment: Beware `-mtime +1` is not the complement of `-mtime -1`. `'(' -mtime 1 -o -mtime +1 ')'` would be.

Comment: File names do not contain NULs be contain newlines and command substitution strip trailing newline characters. That would only be a problem with things like `find $'\n\n\n' ...` though.

Answer (score 0):

`mtree` is specifically designed for this sort of thing, such as verifying that a directory full of binaries has not been overwritten with malicious or corrupted code, or any use case where you want to check whether a set of files are free from unexpected changes (whether in data or metadata).

Create (`-c`) a reference file `my_dir.mtree` of your directory (`-p my_dir`), including the `-K sha256` digest:

```
$ sudo mtree -c -p my_dir -K sha256 > my_dir.mtree
```

The next time you want to check whether any files have been modified, run `mtree` again giving it just the `-p` path option and your mtree specification file:

```
$ sudo mtree -p my_dir < my_dir.mtree
```

Any files that differ will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

With zsh,

```
if ()(($#)) **/????*(NDY1m-1); then
  echo There are files or directories last modified within the last 24 hours
fi
```

- `() {body} args` defines and runs an [anonymous function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) whose body here is the `(($#))` arithmetic expression which returns true if `$#` (the number of arguments) is non-zero
- `**/` any level (including 0) of directories, short for extendedglob's `(*/)#`. Note that `.` itself is not considered, you can replace `**/` with `{.,**/}` if you want it to be considered.
- `N`: nullglob [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): don't complain if there's no match and instead pass an empty list to the anonymous function.
- `D`: dotglob, don't skip hidden files.
- `Y1`: stop at the first match as an optimisation
- `m-1`: last `m`odified in the last day (24 hours) like `find`'s `-mtime -1`.

With `set -o extendedglob`, you can use `?(#c4,)` instead of `????*` to match on files with at least 4 characters in their name.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
if find . -name '????*' -mtime -1 | LC_ALL=C grep -q '^'; then
  echo There are files last modified within the last 24 hours
fi
```

May be slightly more efficient if there's a large number of matching files, as `grep -q` will exit as soon as it reads one line of input, after which `find` will be killed the next time it writes something to the pipe.

As `find` will buffer its output as it's going to a pipe, it won't be killed as soon as the first file is found though.

With GNU or FreeBSD `find`, you can do:

```bash
if [ -n "$(find . -name '????*' -mtime -1 -print -quit)" ]...
```

On NetBSD, the equivalent is with `-exit`. With GNU `find`, you can replace `-print` with `-printf .` as a tiny optimisation.

You could also do things like:

```bash
if [ -n "$(
  find . -name '????*' -mtime -1 -exec sh -c 'echo .; kill -s PIPE "$PPID"' ';'
  )" ]...
```

Where `find` invokes `sh` to output something and kill its parent.